# How do I automate testing of drawings in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple query, how do I test or verify a drawing in WPF? Suppose I have a code stub to draw a rectangle as follows,

```
    DrawRectangle(fill, pen, rect);
```

Is there a way where I can test and verify whether the rectangle has been drawn with the settings I opt for, without manual interaction? Currently, as a developer, I have to look on the screen to check and verify, can I automate this?
 I am looking for something on the lines of UI automation testing, like using squish or other tools. I tried coded UI testing and squish, but they test the UI part, but not the drawing part. 
Please guide.TIA.

Comment: Hmm, if the UI shows the right thing, then drawing worked well. So yes, test the UI part.

Comment: Other than manually inspecting for correctness, Is there another way? As snoop analyses the tree and as squish analyses the UI, is there a tool to check the correctness of drawings?